# Is there a way to loop back to the beginning of a certain part of the code in python

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop, back

I was writting a script to check if the lenght of an input word is equal to a certain number, and if not loop back again to the the input question.

I used the following code,

```
x=input("input a word")

y=len(x)

while y<8 or 8<y:

  print("word must have 8 
         characters")

    continue

  print("word accepted")

    break
```

But the problem is when looping back using "continue" it won't loop back to the input question. Also input question can't be written inside the while loop because it gives out an error "x is not defined".

So how can I loop back to the input question in here.Is there anyway to do that.

Comment: Wrap all into a `while True`. Or use recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways of doing it, using a `while True`:

```
while True:
    x=input("input a word: ")
    if len(x) == 8:
        break
    print("word must have 8 characters")
```

Using recursion:

```
def get_input():
    x=input("input a word: ")
    if len(x) == 8:
        return x
    print("word must have 8 characters")
    return get_input()
```

Comment: I'm suspicious of your recursive solution. You are ignoring the return value in the recursive call.

Comment: You're right. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The length is already assigned before `while` loop, so you will never get a new input. You have to get an input inside `while` loop, so that you can get a new input again and again.

This works as you want:

```
while True:
    x = input("input a word: ")
    if len(x) != 8:
        print("word must have 8 characters")
        continue
    else:
        print("word accepted")
        break
```

Comment: May be worth mentioning that for python >= 3.8 you can also simplify using the `:=` operator: `while len(x := input("input a word:")) != 8: print("word must have 8 characters")`

Answer (score 0):

```py
while True==True:
  x=input("input a word")
  y=len(x)
  if y==8:
    print("word accepted")
    break
  else:
    print("word must have 8 characters")
    # continue
```

Comment: ...please don't use `while True == True`. `while True` is much more idiomatic.